# How to reduce The size of com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.SelectItem

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

[image]

When i am working with Gwt, With SelectItem Where i need to reduce the size the text in side selectItem option area.Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

In a CSS create a Style.

```
.newSelectItemFontStyle{
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px; 
}
```

Edit the font-size with the size you want and in code, set the style to the SelectItem:

```
selectItem.setTextBoxStyle("newSelectItemFontStyle")
```

OR you cant edit the original CSS .selectItemText in skin_styles.css so you dont need to call setTextBoxStyle but beware, this will change ALL the select items you have in your application.